# Running WebView in background?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView application that plays music with a flash player and I would like this to continue playing as the user presses the home button and uses other apps. Is there a way to have WebView run in the background and have this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are the way music players are generally implemented on android.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
A WebView is a is a something that gets displayed on the screen. Because services work in the background they don't really have UIs Im not sure what you'll have to use to hook up to your online content but your probably going to want to do it from inside a service.